# Question upvote impossible on Safari on iPad

Tags: bug, design, ipad, safari

[Another user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44022602#44022602) & I observed the following:

**We can not upvote questions when using an iPad.**

This effect is happening

- only for questions
- only for upvotes
- only on iPad (will check and edit with specific details)
- when using Safari
- on graduated sites p, e.g. Seasoned Advice and English Language Learners.

All other voting functions are fine and the effect does not happen on an  iPhone. The app is also not affected.

Comment: On all sites or only on Cooking.se? No difference between meta.cooking.se and other sites?

Comment: Can you upvote on German Language.SE?

Comment: It might be that the common factor is if the site has a design or not? So on all beta sites it will work?

Comment: Reproduced (but switching to mobile view is a workaround). I can upvote on German.SE, Puzzling.SE and on Meta.SE, but not on ELL.SE.

Comment: Okay, probably the new design work to make the sites responsive that causes issues

Comment: Does that browser have developer tools so you can see client side errors?